# Trouble understanding about Connect middleware

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

The code below uses the Connect middleware framework.

```
var connect = require("connect");
var app = connect();
var api = {};

var names = ["A","B","C","D"];

names.forEach(function(name) {
 var server = connect();
 app.use(server);
 api["use" + name] = server.use.bind(server);
});
```

I am a noob, and don't understand the code, 
1) app itself gets a `connect()` function, why need it use another `connect()` function(namely, `app.use(server)` )? 
2) if `var server = connect();`
 and `app.use(server);` are moved from forEach, is code equivalent to the previous ?

```
  var server = connect();
  app.use(server); 

names.forEach(function(name) {
      api["use" + name] = server.use.bind(server);
   });
```

3) the statement `api["use" + name] = server.use.bind(server);`
 will create 4 different server(useA,useB,useC,useD), am I right?

Comment: Learn JavaScript in first place, please.

Comment: The very first what you wrote for example: `app itself is a connect() function` - completely wrong. `app` is what `connect` function returns. It could be really anything but in this case it is an object with lots of prototyped functions like `use` function.